# git in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a problem in visual studio.

I tried to create a new repository for a project and when I want to commit, in the "changes"  label it shows me much more files than the files of the project (more than 100,000).
I do not know what those files are or how they got there.
whenever I just click or even scroll on any of those files, visual studio not responding and is stuck, I notice that it's the same in any project I tried to create.
when I tried to commit and push anyway it stuck again and nothing has happened.

I am working with visual studio 2019 enterprise.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which files are shown? Are you opening a solution or a folder. Do you have a `.gitignore` in the root folder?

Comment: @Alexander Schmidt.      all the files from C:\Users\Lenovo
i was looking for some setting to change the directory of where it takes the files from, but i found nothing and vs keep crashing when i just go to "git changes". i opened  solution. and i do have the file of gitignore in

Comment: What happens to the `git changes` toolbox when you open VS without any solution? Select "Contiue without code" in the splash screen.

Comment: @Alexander Schmidt.  the toolbox displays the default open screen.

meaning- the option to create git repos, or clone a repos.

that's what it showed at the beginning,
and after I tried to create the repository, somehow it took all the files from my drive.

I tried again to open a different project that is connected to different repos, and it seems fine there.

Comment: So this means that the repos was created in your `C:\Users\Lenovo` folder. Check if there is an `.git` folder using the cmd `dir "C:\Users\Lenove". If it shows a git-folder there you should delete it and restart VS.

Comment: You could run the command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the repo path to know where it has been created to see if it has not been created in your project folder (i.e too high in the folder tree).

Comment: @Alexander Schmidt .  Thank you, apparently the repos was created there (C:\Users\Lenovo), now after I deleted the git folder it seems that it deleted all the files from the changes lable.
but now when I'm trying to create the repos (right-click on solution-->create git repos ) in the Local path i cannot edit it (it shows me C:\Users\Lenovo), it doesn't let me write or even paste anything.
I tried to open another project and it was all the same.
maybe it was like that before and caused to the initiall problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to use git-initialization from VS in this case. Follow these steps:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Delete are `.git` folders you created with Visual Studio in the file system.
3. Open a shell console (cmd.exe) in your folder `C:\Users\Lenovo`.
4. Execute `mkdir test`.
5. Execute `cd test`.
6. Execute `git init`.
7. Open Visual Studio.
8. `File->New Solution` and select `C:\Users\Lenovo\test` as the destination path.

See if this fixes your problem. If yes then just use `git init` or `git clone` on the console as your entry-point to git. VS git integration is clumsy in many areas. I use it al lot and decided to perform certain commands on the console rather (always the safest option with git).

Comment: many thanks, I did as you mentioned and was able to create a new project and it all worked there (in the origin project it still did not work, so I copied all the files to the new one).